# Is it possible to get app_offline to be ignored when running in visual studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a web app that has an app_offline.htm file, this file is stored in source control along with everything else.

The problem I have is that each time I (or any other developer) do a get latest on the source I get the app_offline.htm file and then when I try to run the app all I see is the app_offline rather than the actual web site.

Is there way that I can stop this from happening?

Answer (score 2):

You can right click on the file and choose exclude from project. It renames the file so you IIS won't pick it up, but I'm pretty sure that Visual Studio will not remember that after you do a new checkout. (*Can't verify this though*)

Other than renaming it or removing it locally, it most certainly depends on your source control system. The whole point of source control is to "restore" a code source to a specific point. Checking out something other than the current state is kind of against the source controls principle..

Can you perhaps rename the file in source control and when you publish it you rename it to app_offline.htm *then* instead?

Comment: Excluding from project renames the file? Don't think so. Last sentence is the way I'd go here. Rename the file as part of your deploy process.